# Does Promise.race rejects the other promises after first fulfillment?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Something that I cannot find the exact answer.
In `Promise.race` after the first fulfillment takes place, do the rest promises keep running or they are rejected?

Comment: I think they both still run https://jsfiddle.net/jnsfdvt2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **yes**, they keep running.
You can see the answer yourself

```js
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('completing promise1 after 1 sec')
    resolve('one');
  }, 1000);
});

const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('completing promise2 after .5 sec')
    resolve('two');
  }, 500);
});

Promise.race([promise1, promise2]).then((value) => {
  console.log(value);
  // Both resolve, but promise2 is faster
});
```

Comment: I believe it's not clear if this behavior comes from Promise.race or SetTimeOut. Couldn't be the SetTimeOut set and be run?

Comment: @NikosIliakis Try swapping the setTimeouts with fetches?

Comment: @NikosIliakis I think promise can not be rejected from outside. Anyway, interesting point, I checked the old JS implementation of Promise and yeah, `Promise.race()` just resolves as soon as any of 
passed promises resolve  https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/3.29.45/src/promise.js?autodive=0/#306